# How to avoid square brackets when converting list to JSON using jsonlite::toJSON in R?

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have a list `my_list <- list(name="Fred", age="5")`

I expected `my_list %>% toJSON` to return `{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}`

Instead, it returns `{"name":["Fred"],"age":["5"]}`

How can I convert this list to JSON whilst avoiding the square brackets?

Answer (score 6):

We can use the `auto_unbox` which is by default `FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
my_list %>% 
   toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)
#{"name":"Fred","age":"5"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `auto_unbox` (the default is `FALSE`)

```
toJSON(my_list, auto_unbox =T)
```